# Enable accurate marker location of drag and drop on Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a page with a satellite view of a building and an aligned floor plan overlay.  There are images that need to be associated with specific locations within the building, so I want to drag an image, drop it on the map and use the position data for other tasks.

I have the concept working at

```
http://130.111.148.131/JMCTour/admin/setCoordinates.php?floor=1,
```

but the marker accuracy leaves much to be desired.  If you go to the site and drop a marker, you can see the location varies widely.  This is true regardless of using

```
point = (pageX, pageY),
point = (screenX, screenY),
location = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(point),
location = overlay.getProjection().fromcontainerPixelToLatLng(point)
```

My code is

```
//draggable handler of each photo
$(".photo").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move",
  containment: $("#photosGallery") ? $("#container") : "document"

});

//droppable handler of the map div
$("#map").droppable({
  drop: function(e){
    var point = new google.maps.Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    var data = {
      "location": overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(point)
    };

    placeMarker(data);
  }
});

//create a new marker overlay at point
function placeMarker(location){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location.location,
    map: map,
    zIndex: 1000,
    draggable: true
  });
}
```

I'd like to have the accuracy working.  While it is true that I can drop a location and drag it to the correct spot, it would be very helpful to have an accurate location on first drop

Answer (score 1):

I have an [**old V2 demo here**](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_user_defined_marker.html), which might help you. It gets the exact lat/lon, with 6 decimals precision, when you drop the marker.
The problem with your code is that **e.pageX, e.pageY** relate to the whole page and not just to the div containing the map.